# Replace nuSOAP with cURL

Tags: php, curl, nusoap

I have a PHP script that syncs data with a third party service, and I would like to, if possible, replace nuSOAP with cURL as I have heard cURL is faster. The web service I am calling just takes simple HTTP post and returns it, so the cURL parameters shouldn't be too involved.

I need to pass 4 things, a user id, password, organization id, and the name of the web service to receive data from.

Which part of the cURL options do I pass them? I was trying to pass them in the header, but I am not sure if that is correct. I kept receiving 'Bad Request (Invalid Number)' error.

Edit: I am setting the HTTPHEADER but it looks like its still setting it to text/html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, i have a thought that you have some basic understanding of cURL. I am giving you some shallow information.

If you are just posting some information to a page make use of

```
curl_setopt($agent, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($agent, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
```

where `$post_data` will be the information you post to the page , something like

```
$post_data="name=stanley&feedback=good";
```

Or

If you are trying to make an authentication to a page, Just use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_USERPWD, '[username]:[password]');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you say 'The web service I am calling just takes simple HTTP post', assuming it *doesn't* use SOAP, you would do it by:

```
 curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_POST,true);
 curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array(
      'user_id'  => 'user',
      'password' => 'pass' //etc, all the key/value pairs you need.
     ));
```

However, if it **is** a SOAP service, you would have to make a SOAP request, and which for it would take we cannot tell you without a WSDL. Any of the PHP XML packages would do to create it, possibly for simple things even normal string manipulation.

A help in the built-in soapclient (not nusoap) would be to do a request with `SOAPClient` and just examine the output of `__getLastRequest()`.